# Why ZendFramework $this->getFrontController()->getBaseUrl() is returning empty string inside a controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, controller

I'm using ZendFramework 1.11.11 for my application and I need know the URL (more specifically the path) that fire up my controller inside my controller.

When I try

```
$this->getFrontController()->getBaseUrl();
```

an empty string is returned. I test that code with the default application created by ZendStudio and accessing it typing http://test.com/default/index/index and nothing.

Any idea how get the URL that fireup a controller inside the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base url is the offset from the original slash that you've set up in your configuration. You do not have a base url, as default is the name of the module, index is the controller, and index is the action.

For firing up another controller, check out this link http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods

To get the current path in a Zend fashion from a controller, do the following.

```
$this->getRequest()->getPathInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok I understand, but how I can get the URL that fireup my controller? I just put that example and as you said the base url is empty in my example, but what I need is know the whole path inside the controller.

Comment: Are you able to use $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] ?

Comment: That works, but what about something more zendframeworknic ;)

Comment: Excellent! That works too and I can't imagine a more zendframeworknic way to get that info ;)